# Extend "Hey Siri" Timeout?

Tags: iphone, siri

If I breathe or pause longer than half a nanosecond, Siri decides I'm done talking and ends the command there.

"Hey Siri remind me tonight at 11 to update vmware tools on---" I couldn't even get the server name out. I hadn't paused for even a fraction of a second.

How do I extend this on the iPhone Xs Max?

P.S. I've noticed Google has this same problem on Gboard.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the time out limit by pressing the Home Button until you stop speaking. This way Siri won’t stop till you release the home button.

As you have no home button try holding down the right side button while you speak.

Comment: So "hey siri" is pretty much useless because of this timeout issue?

Comment: @Sephethus  pretty much